# Tradução de mensagem de conflito de edição

Tags: bug, tradução, internacionalização

Na fila de análise de edições sugeridas, eu estava editando uma resposta (botão "Melhorar") e ao salvá-la apareceu esta mensagem em uma barra marrom no topo da página:

> This post has been edited 2 times since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.

Obviamente, esta mensagem é um tanto rara e difícil de se encontrar, uma vez que edições concomitantes são bastante incomuns. Mas deveria ser traduzida.

Proponho a seguinte tradução:

> Esta mensagem foi editada 2 vezes desde que você começou. A sua edição só poderá ser salva se ela for mais minunciosa do que a edição salva até este momento.

Com o detalhe de observar questões de singular vs plural ("1 vez", "2 vezes", "3 vezes"...)